# Ruby class called as a method

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to define a class such that you can call that class *as a method* to execute desired code? For example (doesn't work):

```
class MySpecialClass
  def self(x)
    x*x
  end
end
```

In a console:

```
MySpecialClass(4)
=> 16
MySpecialClass(5)
=> 25
```

I can't seem to find anything on this online, however some Ruby (2.1.2) classes seem capable of similar behavior, e.g. `String`:

```
String("hello")
=> "hello"
String(3)
=> "3"
```

Note that this is not the same behavior as the `String#new` class method:

```
String.new(3)
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All you have to do is define a method with the same name as the class:

```
def MySpecialClass(x)
  x * x
end
```

`String(foo)` is actually calling the [`Kernel#String`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Kernel.html#method-i-String) method.

Comment: Your method has nothing to do with the class. For example, after defining the class and method you can abandon the class to garbage collection and the method will continue to exist: `MySpecialClass(4) => 16; MySpecialClass.is_a? Class => true; alias m MySpecialClass; MySpecialClass = nil; alias MySpecialClass m; MySpecialClass(4)
=> 16; MySpecialClass.is_a? Class => false`. You certainly would not want that behaviour.

Comment: I see I didn't need to alias the method before setting `MySpecialClass` to `nil`--the method continues to exist.